# Why does the RDD works slower than usual List in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I wanted to compare efficiency of RDD compared to usual `List` in scala spark.

```
val list = Range(1, 1000000, 1)
val dist_list = sc.parallelize(list)

val start_time = System.nanoTime
val sum = list.reduce((x,y) => x+y)
println(s"for list time is      ${System.nanoTime - start_time}")

val s_time = System.nanoTime
val dist_sum = dist_list.reduce((x,y) => x+y)
println(s"for dist_list time is ${System.nanoTime - s_time}")
```

and got the result

```
for list time is      24849500
for dist_list time is 378051900
```

which means RDD 15 times slower than usual operations. Why could that happen?

Comment: Do you expect your RDD code to outperform the list version? Why?

Comment: I believed that parallelized versions should work faster for such tasks, in other case what is their sense?

Comment: This is a common misconception. There must be a threshold from which parallelizing operations becomes optimal. Just parallelizing operations adds overhead related to scheduling parallel tasks. Unless the dataset is large enough to dwarf this overhead, using multiple threads can indeed slow your operation down. And this is not even to talk about Spark's heavier scheduling system. In other words, your assumptions and expectations are not fully correct. What you can count on is that the larger the dataset, the more likely Spark will perform better, but there's a threshold at which it starts.

Comment: Note that this is not an appropriate way of benchmarking. Also, how many executors do you have configured? Maybe it is even running in one thread. Finally, **Spark** is intended for distributed computing, not parallel computing, if you will only have one machine then you wold be better with the parallel collections or **Futures**.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `list.reduce` doesn't even necessarily involve a `List`.

Comment: @ernest_k, it's not just a matter of dataset size.  For any size set of `Int` you could reasonably expect to compute a sum for in a single JVM (e.g. no subset of those `Int`s would overflow), I'd expect the non-Spark version would outperform Spark, simply because adding two integers is so fast that the coordination overhead would dwarf performing additions in a loop.

Comment: @LeviRamsey Right. Reducing this to a single variable (dataset size) was an oversimplification on my part. There's also *how* threads are managed (Spark or just about any concurrent programming API), how many threads there are, and of course what the task itself is, etc. As you say, adding millions of integers is almost always going to be faster with one or a few threads in a process; but running two tasks that take one minute each, like calling a slow web service, can obviously be improved with multiple threads.